# LWC: Variable does not exist: BOOLEAN_TYPE

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, illuminatedcloud

When I try to deploy my LWC component, I'm getting this error: Variable does not exist: BOOLEAN_TYPE.
The most strange thing is that I can retrieve this component from the sandbox and can't deploy it back because of the error.
I think this is a new sfdx issue. Anyone experienced this?

P.S. I am using illuminated cloud 2 v2.1.7.9, and sfdx-cli/7.100.0 linux-x64 node-v14.17.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, new lame updates from salesforce. Instead of informing with an error that the class doesn't compile, as it was before (i.e. no such method) they now just send you a direct error from the controller class

Comment: Please close the question if it's resolved

Comment: I can't, it says I can do so only in 2 days

Comment: ok, please then close it in 2 days